# How to make Markdown to HTML conversion more SEO friendly in Pagedown editor

Tags: html, seo, markdown, pagedown

I am converting markdown to html in pagedown editor in the following way:

```
<div id="question_div" class="post_text">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

   var q_converter = new Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
   $("#question_div").html(q_converter.makeHtml(<?php echo json_encode($q_detail);?>));
});
</script>
```

This is working well. The problem is, guess the value of `$q_detail` is `This is not **working** well`. When I open the `view page source` page, it displays something like

```
$("#question_div").html(q_converter.makeHtml("This is not **working** well"));
```

which I guess is not SEO friendly.

How can I make it display the `$q_detail` like `This is not <b>working</b> well` outside of the `<script>` tag to make it more SEO friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that :

```
<?php include('Parsedown.php') ?>

<div id="question_div" class="post_text">
<?php echo $parsedown->parse($q_detail);?>
</div>
```

After installing [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/)

Comment: This outputs `"This is not **working** well"`. But I want to display it like `This is not <b>working</b> well`. No `""`. Can you share another way to do it.

Comment: How can I do that? Any example would be better to understand.

Comment: What about sanitization? Is parsedown do sanitization also?

Comment: I don't know but you'll have to check.

Comment: I am testing it on its demo page. It only parses html, but not sanitizing.

Comment: I'm trying to get jeff atwood's html sanitizing code in refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-htm. But it is showing OFFLINE.

Comment: I tried parsedown demo and the `script` tag was removed.

Comment: I tried (this div is not inside pre code)`<div>` and than `<h3>something...</h3>`(inside pre code). demo shows that *markdown php* put the `<h3>` inside a `<pre><code>`, but parsedown turn it into html. It breaks layout.